# Different installation folder structure in ClickOnce

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce, manifest

I have a `Visual Studio 2013` solution containing 6 projects, let's call them `A, B, C, D, E, F`. Project A is the main project and references all other projects B, C, D, E, F. The additional libraries need to stay in a folder called `libs` relative to the executable program file of project A. There is another folder called `plugIns` in which the DLL's of the projects B, C and D reside and they are loaded upon start of project A dynamically. The projects E and F are just normal projects with some helper classes.

Now my problem is, that I want to deploy my application with ClickOnce. The folder structure on the server is as follows:

- setup.exe
- A.application
- publish.htm
- Application Files

  - A_1_0_0_0

    - All DLL's, executable file, manifest, ...

In the last mentioned folder the required folder structure is missing:

- Application Files

  - A_1_0_0_0

    - libs

      - All DLL's, except plugins
    - plugIns

      - PlugIn DLL's of project B, C, D

How can I achieve this using ClickOnce out of Visual Studio 2013? I also palyed around with `manifest file`, but after that I cannot compile the program anymore, cause the "`codebase`" of the different DLL's was relative to WHAT?!?!?. I need the codebase to be relative, cause the development takes part from different people.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when trying to deploy an application that used MEF extensions in an Extensions folder. The only solution appeared to be to use MAGE in scripts, outside of VS. I got my scripts to work following the advice on using MAGE.exe at https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/xc3tc5xx%28d=hv.2,v=vs.120%29.aspx

I did have to add some options not specified in the MSDN guidance in order to get this to work exactly as I wanted (e.g. my company as publisher, not MS, on deployment; use manifest for trust; create Start Menu shortcut)